# Are conditions supported in Maven resource filtering?

Tags: java, maven, velocity

I was wondering if there's a way to do `if`-conditions in Maven resource filtering. E.g. something that allows me to do:

somefile.txt:

```
...
#if($some.project.property == true)
  some text to include here
#endif
...
```

Something similar to velocity.

Comment: Maven uses Velocity, and yes, you should be able to use that code, with a few syntax changes. Did you try it?

Comment: I've tried that code, it didn't work.  It only outputs the if/else code in my resource file instead of interpreting it.  Are you sure about maven using velocity?  Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: See [this filtered resource](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-commons/blob/master/xwiki-commons-tools/xwiki-commons-tool-license-resources/src/main/resources/META-INF/NOTICE.vm) for example, along with the [POM configuration](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-commons/blob/master/xwiki-commons-pom/pom.xml#L49-65).

Comment: Make sure the file __is__ filtered. Does a simple `${variable}` get printed correctly?

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu Maven uses Velocity for site generation but not for resource filtering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer no. But if you really need conditions you might take a look into the [velocity-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/velocity-maven-plugin/wiki/HowToUseThePlugin) which solve your problem but it's not intended to filter resources but your use case it might work.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.velocity-maven-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
            <templateFiles>
                    <directory>/src/main/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                            <include>*.vm</include>
                    </includes>
            </templateFiles>
            <templateValues>
                    <test>foo</test>
            </templateValues>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise. Yeah, I thought so too.

Comment: FYI, in my example, yes the resource is being filtered correctly.  I can have the variables replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting a property (per profile) might be useful in some cases.

```
<yourProperty><![CDATA[
    <your>
        <block>of code</block>
    </your>
    ]]></yourProperty>
```

If you don't want the block of code, set the property to an empty string.

I used this for example to inject a `<data-source>` into my `web.xml` for development builds.